# Lightgbm gpu installation

Tags: machine-learning, installation, lightgbm

I am trying to run Lightgbm with gpu on Spyder. For installing the library I tried many commands but most have failed.

1. I tried "pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu" in anaconda prompt and got the
   [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZW1r.png).
2. The I followed the https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Installation-Guide.rst#build-gpu-version

I installed git, vs 2022, cmake and opencl(Cuda Toolkit)
For boost binaries I copied the boost_1_78_0 file in "C:\Boost".
But the file doesn't contain any "lib64-msvc-14.0"(or similar folder). **This is the first problem** but it contain libs folder so I gave that path(Hope that's right).
But then I get this error:

CMake Warning:
No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

"CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/*User Name*/LightGBM/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks